# What are the naming conventions for Java .properties files?

Tags: java, properties, naming-conventions

I plan to create a **global properties** file for use across the application, and several properties files available only for specific classes and methods. Is there any particular industry standard for naming the property files?

Comment: Some application frameworks use a conventions. The NetBeans Rich Client Platform and modules system uses Bundle.properties in miscellaneous package directories. In general though, the less the better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no set rule.

The naming convention I go by is if it is a properties for a single class, I use `{ClassName}.properties`, otherwise I use `{WhatIsItUsedFor}.properties`, and occasionally if it's for a single application, `{ApplicationName}.properties`.  I have a preference for CamelCase; others prefer lowercase.

For the names of properties themselves, if granularity is possible, I use something like

```
{ClassName}.{MethodNameIfNeeded}.{IntendedVariable}={value}
```

Do realize the more property files you have, the more potential maintenance issues you create. Some are better off consolidating to a single properties file, using the property/value naming convention (above) to single-out any classes requiring their own configuration.

Comment: Camel Case definitely makes it clearer to read, especially when the {IntentedVariable} portion becomes quite long.

Answer (score 5):

No; name them something meaningful to the context in which they'll be used.

You'll see things like "applicationResources.properties", "messages.properties", etc. right alongside filenames that have more business-specific meanings, like "account.properties".

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: no

Typically you'd name the global properties 'myapp.properties'. Have a look around at some confgiration frameworks, see if they do what you want.  Such as [commons-configuration](https://commons.apache.org/configuration/).

Answer (score 5):

The naming is more complex if you consider also localization.
See [Java doc for `java.util.ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29):

> baseName + "_" + language + "_" + script + "_" + country + "_" + variant

Examples:

```
MyResource_fr_FR
MyResource_fr_CA
MyResource_fr_CH
MyResource_en_Latn_US_WINDOWS_VISTA
MyResource_en_Latn_US_WINDOWS
MyResource_en_Latn_US
MyResource_en_Latn
MyResource_en_US_WINDOWS_VISTA
MyResource_en_US_WINDOWS
MyResource_en_US
MyResource_en
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  Name the file with a .properties extension (I've also seen .prp).

I would recommend against using a "global" properties file, and instead maintain like configurations in segregated files, i.e.:

```
database.properties
smtp.properties
messages.properties
```